# In a right angled $\triangle ABC$, right angled at $A$, $AD\perp BC$

Tags: geometry

In a right angled $\triangle ABC$, right angled at $A$, $AD\perp BC$. Prove that: $$\dfrac {1}{AB^{2}}=\dfrac {1}{AD^{2}} - \dfrac {1}{AC^{2}}$$

My Attempt:
$$\dfrac {1}{AB^{2}}=\dfrac {AC^{2}- AD^{2}}{AC^{2}.AD^{2}}$$
$$AB^{2}=\dfrac {AC^{2}.AD^{2}}{AC^{2}-AD^{2}}$$
$$AB^{2}=\dfrac {(BC^{2}-AB^{2})(AB^{2}-BD^{2})}{BC^{2} - AB^{2} - AB^{2} + BD^{2}}$$

Comment: What is $D{}{}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach $1$:**

From area of triangle, we have

$$\frac12(AB)(AC)=\frac12(AD)(BC)$$

$$[(AB)(AC)]^2=[(AD)(BC)]^2$$

Hence, by Pythagoras theorem,

$$(AB)^2(AC)^2 = (AD)^2(AC^2+AB^2)$$

$$(AB)^2[(AC)^2-(AD)^2]=(AD)^2(AC)^2$$

$$AB^2 = \frac{(AD)^2(AC)^2}{AC^2-AD^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{AB^2}=\frac{AC^2-AD^2}{(AD)^2(AC)^2}=\frac1{AD^2}-\frac1{AC^2}$$

**Approach $2$:**
Alternatively, if you want to press on from your approach:

$$AB^{2}=\dfrac {(BC^{2}-AB^{2})(AB^{2}-BD^{2})}{BC^{2} - AB^{2} - AB^{2} + BD^{2}}$$

$$AB^{2}(BC^{2} - 2AB^{2}  + BD^{2})=(BC^{2}-AB^{2})(AB^{2}-BD^{2})$$

$$(AB)^2(BC)^2-2(AB)^4+(AB)^2(BD)^2=(AB)^2(BC)^2-(BC)^2(BD)^2-(AB)^4+(AB)^2(BD)^2$$

$$(BC)^2(BD)^2=(AB)^4$$

$$(BC)(BD)=AB^2$$

$$\frac{BD}{AB} = \frac{AB}{BC}$$

which is a true statement which can be deduced using similar triangle.

Comment: How did you write the step just below " Hence, by Pythagoras theorem,"??

Comment: $BC^2=AC^2+AB^2$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
 Prove that 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|AB|^2}&=\frac{1}{|AD|^{2}} - \frac{1}{|AC|^{2}} 
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|AB|^2}+\frac{1}{|AC|^{2}}&=\frac{1}{|AD|^{2}}
,\\
\frac{|AB|^2+|AC|^{2}}{|AB|^2\,|AC|^{2}}&=\frac{1}{|AD|^{2}}
,\\
\frac{|BC|^2}{|AB|^2\,|AC|^{2}}&=\frac{1}{|AD|^{2}}
,\\
|BC|^2\,|AD|^{2}&=|AB|^2\,|AC|^{2}
,\\
(2S_{\triangle ABC})^2
&=
(2S_{\triangle ABC})^2
.\\
\end{align}